# Snyk monitor command is failing

Tags: snyk

I am running below SNYK command for standard WAS application.

```
snyk monitor --all-projects
```

It is failing because there is a war-src module which contains `${project.version}` tag and this version is mentioned in main pom.xml inside property tag...when i run snyk monitor command it is not picking up the version `${project.version}` and throwing error.

In snyk document saw that we can pass maven options using build tool command. Whatever command mentioned below is correct? If not, please let me know how can I make use of this?

```
snyk monitor --all-projects -- -Dproject.version=2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the double dash to pass additional arguments to Maven. The command you wrote is the correct way to pass the `-Dproject.version=2.1.0` argument to Maven